# Retrofit POST request with multipart form data not reaching server

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I have an API in which I have to send normal fields alongwith images. For calling the API I am using Retrofit. For sending the multipart request I am using the Multipart Body Builder method. Below is the code for the same.

```
val builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
var jsonArray = JSONArray()
for ((index, value) in lineItems.withIndex()) {
    var jsonObject = JSONObject()

    jsonObject.accumulate("Room_id", lineItems[index].roomId)
    jsonObject.accumulate("jobTitle", lineItems[index].jobTitle)
    jsonObject.accumulate("floorLevel", lineItems[index].floorLevel)
    jsonObject.accumulate("jobTrade", lineItems[index].jobArea)
    jsonObject.accumulate("jobWork", lineItems[index].jobWork)
    jsonObject.accumulate("desc", lineItems[index].desc)
    jsonObject.accumulate("isFixed", lineItems[index].isFixed)
    jsonObject.accumulate("hourlyCost", lineItems[index].cost)
    jsonObject.accumulate("hourlyTotal", lineItems[index].total)
    jsonObject.accumulate("hourlyDuration", lineItems[index].duration)
    jsonObject.accumulate("fixedCost", lineItems[index].fixedCost)
    if (lineItems[index].lineItemId!="") {
        jsonObject.accumulate("_id", lineItems[index].lineItemId)
    }
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject)
    Log.d("json array",jsonArray.toString())

}

builder.addFormDataPart("lineHeight", jsonArray.toString())
for ((i, value) in lineItems.withIndex()) {
    var imageList = ArrayList<String>()

    if (lineItems[i].imageList!=null && lineItems[i].imageList!!.size>0) {
        imageList = lineItems[i].imageList!!

        for ((j, path) in imageList.withIndex()) {
            if (!imageList[j].contains("http")) {
                val file = File(path)
                val requestFile = 
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/"+
                    file.name.substring(file.name.indexOf(".")+1)), file)
                val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photos" + i,
                    file.name, requestFile)
                builder.addPart(body)
            }
        }
    }
 }

val requestBody = builder.build()
```

When I call the above API I get:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   http://18.222.231.171/api/lineheight/5bb45c4485453079ebb14b15 (4637ms)
>   Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
>   Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2018 10:31:23 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Content-Length: 182
>   Connection: keep-alive
>    502 Bad Gateway
>
> ## 502 Bad Gateway
>
> ---
>
> nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

**PS:-** The api works fine in iOS as well as Postman

Here is the call code:

```
fun addLineItems(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                 @Path("jobId") jobId: String,
                 @Body body: okhttp3.RequestBody): Call<Response>
```

I confirmed with a web services guy that they get nothing in the logs when I call this API from the app, while logs are shown when same is called from Postman.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I Tried

This is how I prepared the multipart entity.

```
File file = new File(currentFilePath);
if (file.exists()) {
String name = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(name), file);
MultipartBody.Part multipart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

this is the method to upload the file

```
@Multipart
@POST("your url")
fun uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Path("jobId") jobId: String,
                @Part file: MultipartBody.Part): Call<Response>
```

Probably you should add @Multipart annotayion to your method

Comment: As I am using request body so  adding multipart header causes app to crash. But I will give it a try with @Part

Comment: Same issue with Part map too